# ZF2 - ACL resources in a dynamic roles approach

Tags: zend-framework2

Given a system with static permissions like `posts.create`, `category.edit` and such, and roles that can be created at runtime, both stored in a database but permissions can't (technically shouldn't) be modified; And the relations are `N:M` for `users` to `roles` and for `roles` to `permissions`:

Looking at the ACL package, at first sight it looks like I'd have to build up the ACL graph by querying my database roles on each request and adding them to the ACL instance and the allowed permissions like:

```
// Some class like AclService.php that should be called in Module.php
// ...

$roles = // query db for all roles and their permissions

foreach ($roles as $role) {
    $acl->addRole($role->getName());

    foreach ($role->getPermissions() as $permission) {
        $acl->allow($role->getName(), null, $permission->getName());
    }
}
```

Up to this point, in my controller's action (or a middleware, if they'd exist) I'd check if the user is allowed to execute the action:

```
// CategoryController
public function createAction() {
    $user = // retrieve user from identity

    if (! $acl->isAllowed($user->getRoles()->first(), null, 'categories.create')) {
        // throw a 403 exception
    }
}
```

What I don't get quite yet is, **where does a `Resource` fits in this schema**? Am I missing something here?

Or maybe are resources fit for when the permissions are not as granular as `categories.create` but just `create`?

Comment: categories.create is the resource.. it's like saying does the user have access to the create action on the category controller. it can represent almost anything as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are using  `$acl->addRole($role->getName());` but as per the documentionation it should be defined in resources.

```
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl;
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Role\GenericRole as Role;
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Resource\GenericResource as Resource;

$acl = new Acl();

$acl->addRole(new Role('guest'))
    ->addRole(new Role('member'))
    ->addRole(new Role('admin'));

$parents = array('guest', 'member', 'admin');
$acl->addRole(new Role('someUser'), $parents);

$acl->addResource(new Resource('someResource'));

$acl->deny('guest', 'someResource');
$acl->allow('member', 'someResource');

echo $acl->isAllowed('someUser', 'someResource') ? 'allowed' : 'denied';
```

If this doesn't help then let me know I will try to help.